# How can i use variable in Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have this query :

```
 $result = mysql_query("select * FROM  `agents_infos` 
 WHERE ( agent_name LIKE  '%$name%' )");
```

the $name is :

```
 $name =$_POST['name'];
```

I want to get in the result, all the element that contains the name , but I get nothing. Can you help me please?

Comment: Has your variable $name actually a value? You could try printing it like `echo $name` or check your query `echo "select * FROM agents_infos WHERE ( agent_name LIKE  '%$name%' )"`

Comment: yes , the value is posted , it's printed

Comment: Maybe magic quotes are disabled on your server. Try: `$result = mysql_query("select * FROM  agents_infos WHERE ( agent_name LIKE  '%" . $name . "%' )");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to receive a list of all element that contains the name, you can write:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `agents_infos` WHERE ( agent_name LIKE  '%".$name."%' )");
```

to avoid code injection i advice to use

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['name'] );
```

instead of

> $name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does not prevent injection.

Comment: and the mysql extension is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to sanitize your input: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
then you need to use mysqli instead of mysql : http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

then you can do this:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$query =  "select * FROM  `agents_infos` WHERE ( agent_name LIKE  '%".$name."%' )";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```